# Black screen in url launcher flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

When I pressed the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) action button. And then app minimize it. And then again go back to the app, page will be black screen

[image: issue]

Answer (score 2):

Use as below, It will solve your issue

```
launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using android platform then make sure you have added these below lines in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<queries>
  <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app makes calls -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your sends SMS messages -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app sends emails -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

if you are using IOS platform make sure you have added these below lines in info.plist file-

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>https</string>
  <string>http</string>
</array>
```

And At frontend side

launch(url);//Pass URL inside this method.

Note: Done forget to add required permissions in your app. Like- Internet permission...etc.

Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Issue not solve. Blackscreen exist

Comment: Can you provide me code segment... and more details about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you handle (if else or something) then remove this code and use try catch.Hopefully it will solve your problem.

```
Future<void> openPDFFile({
  required String url,
}) async {
  final uri = Uri.parse(url);
  // if (await launchUrl(uri)) {
  //   await launchUrl(
  //     uri,
  //     mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
  //   );
  // } else {
  //   throw 'Could not launch $url';
  // }
  try {
    await launchUrl(
      uri,
      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
    );
  } catch (e) {
    e.toString().log();
  }
}
```